# Access a structure instance by its name

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to access a field of a structure-instance by another structure-instance or by its name. As this sounds admittedly very confusing, I have one (very constructed) example:

```
(defstruct author
  (name nil)
  (books '())
  (years '()))

(defstruct book
  (name nil)
  (author '())
  (copy-sold '()))

(defparameter hitchikers-guide
  (make-book :name "Hitchikers-Guide"
             :author '(douglas-adams)
             :copy-sold '(a lot)))

(defparameter douglas-adams
  (make-author :name "Douglas Adams"
               :books '(Hitchikers-guide restaurant life-and-universe fish)
               :years '(too few)))

(defparameter authors
  '(douglas-adams pterry))
```

I have the instance `hitchikers-guide`. If I want to look for all the books of its author I can type in the REPL `(author-books douglas-adams)` and I get the list of all his books. However, if I enter

`(author-books (first (book-author hitchikers-guide)))`

or

`(author-books (first authors))`

I get the error message:

> The value DOUGLAS-ADAMS is not of the expected type AUTHOR.

Am I doing it wrong, or is there no way of accessing these fields this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable `authors` contains `symbol`s, not `author`s.

Try

```
(defparameter authors (list douglas-adams pterry))
```

instead (if, of cource, `pterry` has been defined already).

Similarly, `(book-author hitchikers-guide)` is a list of `symbol`s, not `author`s.

You need to use [`symbol-value`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_5.htm) to get the corresponding `author`.

Comment: Note that `symbol-value` only works in this case because the variables are declared special, because they were defined with `defparameter`.  Doing `(defparameter authors (list douglas-adams pterry))` is possible in this case only because `douglas-adams` and (presumably) `pterry` have already been defined.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to look up an object by a symbol as its identifier, you need to use a data structure for that.

The simple version is using symbols in a package.

```
(defun find-object (name)
  (symbol-value name))

(defun intern-object (object name)
  (setf (symbol-value name) object))
```

But you could also use a hash-table:

```
(defvar *my-objects* (make-hash-table))

(defun find-object (name)
  (gethash name *my-objects*))

(defun intern-object (object name)
  (setf (gethash name *my-objects*) object))
```

Comment: In a bit older, but still legal, style you can also stash the object on the property list of the symbol with a known key.  Then you could write retrieve it with [`get`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get.htm), i.e., `(get 'douglas-adams 'author)` would return the `author` object for Douglas Adams.

Comment: It's also a nice practice, though not universal, to talk about _designators_ for a given type.  E.g., a _string designator_ is a character, string, or symbol, and most of the string related function in Common Lisp accept string designators, not just strings. You could define an _author designator_ as an author or a symbol, and have the author related functions take an _author designator_ (by silently mapping the symbol to the author it names).

Answer (score 1):

Which came first - the author or the book?

```
;; first the author
(defstruct (author :conc-name make-author-internal)
  (name nil)
  (books '())
  (years '()))

(defun make-author (name years)
  (make-author-internal :name name :books '() :years years))

(defun author-add-book (author book)
  (setf (author-books author)
        (cons book (author-books author))))

;; now the book, requires an author (assumes one, if >1, use a list)
(defstruct (book :conc-name make-book-internal)
  (name nil)
  (author nil)
  (copy-sold '()))

(defun make-book (name author copy-sold)
  (let ((book (make-book-internal :name name :author author ...)))
    (author-add-book author book)
    book))

 ;; ...

 (defparameter douglas-adams
   (make-author "Douglas Adams" ...))

 (defparameter hitchikers-guide
   (make-book "Hitchikers-Guide" douglas-adams ...))
```